# Android Java | NavigatonDrawer below and above android sdk 33

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

When I use this code everythings works fine untill the device is below android sdk version 33. When I test it with android skd version 34 (Android 14) the app crashes instantly. Anyone could help me how could I edit it to use the navigationdrawer with below and above android sdk 33? Are there any other method for similar output? If I miss something which I should tell more about the code just let me know please.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.my_drawer_layout);
    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.nav_open, R.string.nav_close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // Show hamburger icon

    // Set up hamburger icon click listener
    actionBarDrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        }
    });
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            // Handle navigation item clicks here
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.home:
                    topLayer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    relativeLay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    fragmentContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
                case R.id.about:
                    Log.e("asdasd", "Clicked about option!!!!!!!!");
                    topLayer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    relativeLay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    fragmentContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new aboutFragment()).commit();
                    break;
            }

            // Close the drawer after handling the click
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
    if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: "the app crashes instantly" -- use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash: https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-debug-001.html

Comment: Can you post stack trace of crash .. it can help to identify exact cause

Comment: On android 14 sdk 34 here is the stack trace ```java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.soccer.insight/com.soccer.insight.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference``` below that version everything works fine